# How to automate Azure Site Recovery failover?

Tags: azure, vmware, disaster-recovery, vcenter

I have started exploring Azure Site Recovery with VMware as a disaster recovery solution for our customers. The main doubt I have is on how to automate failovers. I.e. how can I tell Azure to check if an on-prem VM is offline and automatically initiate the failover process? Do I need something like OMS to make it happen or should Automation runbooks or something similar be enough?

Answer (score 1):

OMS does not have the solution to automate. But, automation runbooks like you guessed are supported by ASR. However you cannot use automation for individual VM's per se. You can use automation on recovery plans and have one VM as part of that plan.

This should give you some insight.
    [1]: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-runbook-automation/